# Reading Pane Shofted to Far to the Right

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've hit a combination of keys that has resulted in all the text in my reading pane shifted to the right, and some of it off the screen. The reading pane is on the right, which is where I want it to be, it's just that the text within the reading pane is shifted to the right.

see link for a picture

Thanks for your help,
Mike

Comment: 1. Link is not present. 2. Have you changed language to Right-to-Left, as in Arabic and Hebrew?

Comment: Try clicking View > Reset View.